# Npm install falied in github action

Tags: node.js, npm, github-actions

I tried to create a github action that build my electron app with vue and vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder,but I can't install Dependencies by npm

my folder tree like this:

```
|   .gitignore
|   babel.config.js
|   LICENSE
|   package-lock.json
|   package.json
|   README.md
|   vue.config.js
|   yarn.lock
|
+---public
|       favicon.ico
|       index.html
|       test.jpg
|
\---src
    |   App.vue
    |   background.js
    |   main.js
    |   preload.js
    |
    +---assets
    |       ...
    |
    \---components
            ...
```

when I run the CI,I found a error that

```
  npm ci
  shell: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
npm ERR! The `npm ci` command can only install with an existing package-lock.json or
npm ERR! npm-shrinkwrap.json with lockfileVersion >= 1. Run an install with npm@5 or
npm ERR! later to generate a package-lock.json file, then try again.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\npm\cache\_logs\2021-08-01T04_59_20_385Z-debug.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

this is my blank.yml:

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: CI

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the main branch
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    name: Build
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - name: Install Node.js, NPM and Yarn
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
          node-version: 16
    - name: Install Dependencies
      run: |
            npm ci
    - name: Electron Build
      run: |
            npm run electron:build --windows nsis --x64 --ia32
```

I tried search on bing with the key word "npm install failed in github action" but I found nothing helpful.
also,I tried using 'npm install' instead the 'npm ci', but it showed the same error message that it can't find the package.json
the 'npm install' 's error message like this:

```
Run npm install
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path D:\a\example\example/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\example\example\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\npm\cache\_logs\2021-08-01T05_12_56_060Z-debug.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

How can I solve it?

English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not checking out your code and directly running `NPM CI`.
Below piece of code should do the job for you

```
name: CI
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    name: Build
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout Code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Install Node.js, NPM and Yarn
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
          node-version: 16
    - name: Install Dependencies
      run: |
            npm ci
    - name: Electron Build
      run: |
            npm run electron:build --windows nsis --x64 --ia32
```